# Make Your Own Neural Network Back Propagation

Tags: python, neural-network

I'm reading through the Make Your Own Neural Network book and in the chapter where the author describes about the back propagation, I find myself confused. I would like to relate the way the author explains with an example where he shows a 2 node, 3 layer network sh shown in the image below:

[image: Back Propagation]

If I construct the Matrix representation of the above Neural Network for back propagation, it would look like this:

[image: Matrix Back Propagation]

Where W<sup>T</sup><sub>hidden_output</sub> is a Matrix transpose of the input weights, thus the Matrix representation in details is:

[image: Matrix Detail]

So if I want to now calculate the hidden Errors (e<sub>1_hidden</sub> and e<sub>2_hidden</sub>), I have the following:

> e<sub>1_hidden</sub> = W<sub>11</sub> * e<sub>1</sub> + W<sub>12</sub>
>   * e<sub>2</sub>
>
> e<sub>2_hidden</sub> = W<sub>21</sub> * e<sub>1</sub> + W<sub>22</sub>
>   * e<sub>2</sub>

But if I apply the values as given in the example., where e<sub>1</sub> = 1.5 and e<sub>2</sub> = 0.5, I do not get the e<sub>1_hidden</sub> = 0.7 and e<sub>2_hidden</sub> = 1.3

Where am I going wrong with my understanding / calculation? Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing the error back propagation based on simply **multiplying by link weights**, whereas the picture splits the error in **proportion to the link weights**. Both differences are described e.g. on [this webpage](http://makeyourownneuralnetwork.blogspot.com/2016/07/error-backpropagation-revisted.html):

[image]

In the picture, you see that the error is split in **proportion to the link weights**, e.g. e<sub>1</sub> = 1.5 is split into 0.6 and 0.9 according to the weights of W<sub>11</sub> = 1.0 and W<sub>21</sub> = 3.0. (Note further, that the subscripts of the weights are also wrong in the picture because there is only W<sub>11</sub> and all others are denoted by W<sub>12</sub> ...)

This split up error is then added to the final error of the hidden layer, e.g.:

e<sub>hidden 1</sub> = 0.6 + 0.1 = 0.7.